# VBScript Do While loop skips part of code when nested

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I have this Do...While - Loop VBScript code that works fine in pulling screen data from Bluezone Web-to-Host platform to Excel and then sorting it. However, it requires a passcode to open the records. The variable for this passcode is named `CourtCode` and the value is in `Sheet("Main").Range("B2")`. The VBScript works fine in pulling the records for this single passcode

But when I fill in a list of passcodes in Column B of the same sheet and try to loop through, I discover that it will only show the screen of the records and process the first record only.

Here is the VBScript code:

```
Do While oRow < numberofLoops And Checkr < 1
'For oRow = 1 To numberofLoops

z = 1



'  PF11 - GENERAL LOOK-UPS AND INQUIRY 
bzo.SendKey "<PF11>"
bzo.WaitReady 10, 1


' Enter court code
bzo.SetCursor 8, 37
bzo.SendKey CourtCode
bzo.SendKey "<PF6>"
bzo.WaitReady 10, 1

    ' Loop through X entry



    If oRow > 10 And oRow < 21 Then
            z = z + 10
            bzo.SendKey "<PF8>"
            bzo.WaitReady 10, 1
    End If

    If oRow > 20 And oRow < 31 Then
            z = z + 20
            bzo.SendKey "<PF8>"
            bzo.WaitReady 10, 1

            bzo.SendKey "<PF8>"
            bzo.WaitReady 10, 1
    End If

    If oRow > 30 And oRow < 41 Then
            z = z + 30
            bzo.SendKey "<PF8>"
            bzo.WaitReady 10, 1

            bzo.SendKey "<PF8>"
            bzo.WaitReady 10, 1

            bzo.SendKey "<PF8>"
            bzo.WaitReady 10, 1
    End If

  Do While z < oRow     

        bzo.SendKey "<Down>"
    bzo.WaitReady 10, 100
        z = z + 1
    Loop



    'If oRow = 11 Then 
    '       bzo.SendKey "<Up>"
    '       bzo.WaitReady 10, 1
    'End If

bzo.SendKey "x"
bzo.SendKey "<Enter>"
bzo.WaitReady 10, 1

bzo.SendKey "<PF1>"
bzo.WaitReady 10, 1

    ' Copy first screen
bzo.Copy rcScreen
wb.Sheets("DATA").Activate
wb.Sheets("DATA").Range("A1").Select
wb.Sheets("DATA").Paste

'Go back
bzo.SendKey "<PA2>"
bzo.WaitReady 10, 1

bzo.SendKey "<PF2>"
bzo.WaitReady 10, 1

'Copy second screen
 bzo.Copy rcScreen
wb.Sheets("DATA").Range("N1").Select
wb.Sheets("DATA").Paste

'Go back
bzo.SendKey "<PA1>"
bzo.WaitReady 10, 1

oRow = oRow + 1
eo.Run "Sortr"

Checkr = eo.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN").Range("F2").Value

 Loop
```

In order to repeat this code with a loop I tried:

```
Do While i < numberofpasscodes  ' As found in Excel sheet

  CourtCode = eo.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN").Range("B" & i).Text
   '''''''''''''''
   '  Block of vbscript loop above
   '''''''''''''''
  i = i + 1

Loop
```

The problem I'm facing is that new loop doesn't take more than one record per passcode. Please help. I dont know if I'm missing anything.

Comment: Do you reset  `oRow` on each main loop?

Comment: How did you determine numberofpasscodes? Did you check if it is correctly returned? Did you initialize i at the appropriate value for the starting row?  What `oRow` means? How was it defined in the working code?

Comment: There's a cell in the Sheet that has the numberofpasscodes value = COUNTA(B:B). This VB code gets it - eo.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN").Range("F2").Text where eo stands for Excel Object.                 oRow is a variable for the number pf records in each code in the main code. Defined As Dim oRow As Long

Comment: You might need to reinitialise `oRow` before the inner loop, after getting the new `CourtCode`